# Windows Batch file - pipe to FIND

Tags: windows, batch-file

Trying to test a string to see if it contains a substring in a Windows batch file.

This is what I have so far:

```
echo %1 | find "message"
if %errorlevel% == 0 echo contains string
```

The command line output for this is (the contents of %1 was "messages\Message.js"):

```
messages\Message.js
contains string
```

The issue I am having is that the only way I can get this to work is with the exact line: `echo %1 | find "js"`.

How can I do this without echoing the file path each time? When I remove the `echo`, the operating system attempts to open the file. I would love to save the file path to a variable, but nothing I tried worked, I always ended up with an empty variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    echo %1 | find "message" > NUL
    if %errorlevel% == 0 echo contains string
```